# How will I parse this json

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am new to android an learning web service I tried a lot to look this kind of parsing but unable to find any similar example of this kind

```
[  
{  
  "result":"Success",
  "matches":[  
     {  
        "matchID":"1",
        "matchUniqueID":"1134032",
        "team_one_name":"Zimbabwe",
        "team_two_name":"Afghanistan",
        "dateTimeGmt":"2018-02-06T15:00:00.000Z",
        "match_type":"T20I",
        "match_date":"2018-02-06 00:00:00",
        "is_done":"N"
     },
     {  
        "matchID":"2",
        "matchUniqueID":"1134065",
        "team_one_name":"Kent",
        "team_two_name":"Leeward Islands",
        "dateTimeGmt":"2018-02-06T13:00:00.000Z",
        "match_type":"ListA",
        "match_date":"2018-02-06 00:00:00",
        "is_done":"N"
     }
]
}
]
```

This is what I have tried but unfortunately, it's not working

```
 public class Asy extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(Institute_URL);
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String result=object.getString("result");

                JSONArray innerJsonArray=object.getJSONArray("matches");

                for (int j=0;j<innerJsonArray.length();j++){

                    JSONObject innerObject=innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);


                    Constant.Match_Id.add(String.valueOf(innerObject.get("matchID").toString()));



                    Log.i("jhk",Constant.Match_Id.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is showing String cannot be converted into Json Array

Comment: Can you share something you have tried?

Comment: I have updated my answer @Sid

Comment: what is `Institute_URL`? Is it the JSOn string, or the URL to get it?

Comment: No its not a Json string its a url

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String result=object.getString("result");

                JSONArray innerJsonArray=object.getJSONArray("matches");

                for (int j=0;j<innerJsonArray.length();j++){

                    JSONObject innerObject=innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    String matchID=innerObject.getString("matchID");
                    String matchUniqueID=innerObject.getString("matchUniqueID");
                    String team_one_name=innerObject.getString("team_one_name");
                    String team_two_name=innerObject.getString("team_two_name");
                    String dateTimeGmt=innerObject.getString("dateTimeGmt");
                    String match_type=innerObject.getString("match_type");
                    String match_dat=innerObject.getString("match_dat");
                    String is_done=innerObject.getString("is_done");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: No Its Showing error can u please send me full code thanks in advance @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: please don't write code instead of other people if they don't show any efort. They will become lazy.